# How do I fetch data with a WHERE function?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am running a fetch query as such;

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `myTable` ORDER BY `New_Date` DESC ' ;
$result = $con->query($sql);
```

But just as soon as I try to add a `WHERE` function, it all goes haywire.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE `STATUS` = 'A' ORDER BY `New_Date` DESC ' ;
```

Producing this error;

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'A' (T_STRING)

What I don't understand is, I did this same search in phpMyAdmin successfully and just copied the code EXACTLY. So what am I missing?!

This is the rest of my fetch code.

```
<?php
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
    <ul>
      <li><?php echo $row['LP$']; ?></li>
      <li><?php echo $row['Entry_Date']; ?></li>
      <li><?php echo $row['POOL']; ?></li>
      <li><?php echo $row['WTRFR']; ?></li>
    </ul>
<?php } //end of loop ?>
```

Comment: Because you have unescaped quotes inside quotes - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should escape single quotes `'` with backslashes `\` in the string defined with single quotes `'`:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE `STATUS` = \'A\' ORDER BY `New_Date` DESC ' ;
```

Or use double quotes `"`:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE `STATUS` = 'A' ORDER BY `New_Date` DESC " ;
```

Comment: Arrggh!!  Rookie mistakes :|  thank you!